# Incrementing Euler angles beyond 360 degrees

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a bit confused about some documentation for Unity pertaining to Euler angles. I just want to know if I'm not understanding a difference, or the sample does not follow the best practice. The documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html)
states:

> Only use this variable to read and set the angles to absolute values. Don't increment them, as it will fail when the angle exceeds 360 degrees. Use Transform.Rotate instead.

Meanwhile, the code sample appears to be using increments that could exceed 360 degrees:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public float yRotation = 5.0F;
    void Update() {
        yRotation += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(10, yRotation, 0);
    }
    void Example() {
        print(transform.eulerAngles.x);
        print(transform.eulerAngles.y);
        print(transform.eulerAngles.z);
    }
}
```

Wouldn't incrementing a variable and then using that variable to set the value absolutely still run the risk of exceeding 360 degrees if the variable is over 360 degrees?

Comment: I think that the example is a special case where it is safe to have y increment infinitely because y is the only axis that's being changed regularly, while x and z remain contant.
If all axes would be potentially modifyable, incrementing y might possibly lead to problems when your eulers swap around at 360. You might even get into gimbal lock state. I suppose that's why using Transform.Rotate is recommended.

Answer (score 2):

When you rotate your Object using euler angles then when it reaches 360 and try to exceed further, it becomes (minus)-360 and gradually increase from -359 to -1.

After executing following code your values will not exceed from 360 and will remain positive.

```
float rotateAngle = rotateObject.transform.localEulerAngles.y;
// Convert negative angle to positive angle
rotateAngle = (rotateAngle > 180) ? rotateAngle - 360 : rotateAngle;
rotateObject.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(rotateObject.transform.localEulerAngles.x, rotateAngle, rotateObject.transform.localEulerAngles.z);
```

Comment: Thanks and I get what you're saying, but doesn't the sample code from the doc still run the risk of exceeding 360?

Answer (score 1):

There are differences. When doing:

```
transform.eulerAngles.y += 1F;
```

You are invoking the `+=` operator in `Vector3`.

However, when you set `eulerAngles` this way:

```
float newY = transform.eulerAngles.y + 1F;
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(.., newY, ..);
```

You are invoking a setter in `Transform`, and inside this setter, it probably includes the action of updating `Transform.rotation`.

The difference is that Unity can implement the updating logic in `Transform` class instead of the `Vector3` class, which makes much more sense there.

We can verify this further below in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html):

> Do not set one of the eulerAngles axis separately (eg. eulerAngles.x =
>   10; ) since this will lead to drift and undesired rotations. When
>   setting them to a new value set them all at once as shown above. **Unity
>   will convert the angles to and from the rotation stored in
>   Transform.rotation.**

Comment: Few things to add here is that this applies to Javascript only. Also, to get around that you can actually do something like this: `transform.eulerAngles.y += yRotation % 360;`. You should't but its good to know the work arounds.

Comment: @Programmer you mean that `transform.eulerAngles.y += 1F` works safely in c#? :O

Comment: No. It won't compile. That's the protection about it in C#. This will compile in Javascript and you will get that problem that is mentioned in the doc.

Comment: @Programmer oh I see, interesting, didn't know